# How to convert a string into cl_uchar *?

Tags: c++, opencl

How can I convert (cast) a string

```
char* password = "C & OpenCL is cool";
```

to

```
cl_uchar *
```

to pass it to a cl-kernel function

```
__kernel void foobar(__global const uchar * input_data) {...}
```

?

Comment: `cl_uchar` seems to be a typedef for `unsigned char`. So how about `const cl_uchar *s = (const cl_uchar *)"string literal";`?

Comment: But opencl uses __constant to specify a constant address space. Could __constant also be identical to const ?

Comment: It causes an error in cl::Buffer. I tried char* pwd = "C & OpenCL is cool"; cl_uchar * password = (cl_uchar*) &pwd; - no errors, but it is not const. Next question would be, whether it has to be const.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work without warnings 'n errors:

```
const char* pwd = "C & OpenCL is cool";
cl_uchar * password = (cl_uchar*) &pwd;
cl::Buffer bufferA(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(cl_uchar) * keyBytes, password);
kernel.setArg(0, bufferA);
```

Comment: In which way is this different from the version in my answer, which should work without warnings and errors, too? The additional cast from the `const char*` to `cl_uchar*` is completely useless. In constrast to what you may think, this additional cast doesn't add any additional type-safety at all, since it's just a reinterpret cast, the same that directly putting the `const char*` into the buffer would do.

Comment: Well, yeah, does that justify and additional answer, though, given that the other exiting answers already have the exact same source code? Just remember that this site [is not a forum](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Kill me ;) I think a complete answer also contains CODE, so ppl, who google for the same problem finding this post will also have a direct solution, they can try out.

Comment: Sorry to keep bugging you but I while this might be true I still cannot see how this code is any different from the code in the other answer. You might want to elaborate on that. Like said the 2nd line in plain useless, the 1st line is already part of your question code and the 3rd and 4th lines are an exact copy of an already existing answer, just without any explanations.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly pass that `char` pointer into an OpenCL kernel, since the kernel does not know what to do with that pointer. What you have in the kernel is a pointer into `__global` memory. So what you need to do is create an OpenCL buffer object, write the string into it and pass the handle to this buffer as argument to the kernel. If you don't know how this is done, please consult a proper OpenCL learning resource. In C++ it would be something similar to this:

```
cl::Buffer input_buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, 
                        sizeof(cl_uchar) * (strlen(password)+1), password);
...
kernel.setArg(0, input_buffer);
```

Likewise don't you have to actually convert the `char*` into a `const cl_uchar*`, since you're just copying it into the buffer and on a platform supporting OpenCL `char` and `cl_uchar` can be assumed to have the same bit representation, though for a string literal you should have used `const char*` instead of `char*` in the first place.

By the way, since the data is `const` in the kernel anyway and the string is likely not that large, you might want to consider using `__contant` instead of `__global` memory, which might have performance advantages (at least on older hardware, where `__constant` memory was cached while `__global` wasn't).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Using cl::buffer was clear. Using __constant instead of __global causes an ERROR: **clBuildProgram : -11**.

Comment: @marcus And what *is* `-11`? And what does the build log say? Probably `__constant const` is not the best idea.

Comment: I changed __global to __constant without additional const. There is no log to check out. It just fails to run returing Error -11.

Comment: @marcus You mean the build log as returned by `cl::Program::getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG>()` is empty?

Comment: Using cl::Program::getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG>() causes a compiler error

Comment: @marcus And what error? Just try to get the build log, I cannot chew everything into pieces for you. If you already checked the program's build log and it is empty, then that's fine, but that would be very strange.